# Speed up file reading and writing

Tags: python, file

I want to achieve this, and to do it faster if possible:

1. Go through a list of `users`.
2. Read all files in a directory, the names of which include the name of the user.
3. Grab the contents of each such file, and write it, concatenated, into one file per user.

I have this code, but it is terribly slow:

```
for u in users:
    content = ""
    contentfiles = glob.glob("raw_data/" + "*_" + str(u) + ".txt")
    for c in contentfiles:
        txt = open(c, "r").read()
        content += txt
    with open("docs/" + str(u) + ".txt", "w") as outfile:
        outfile.write(content)
```

Are there faster ways of achieving this? I have 400k users and this is running at about one file per second = 18 hrs.

**Edit: Move glob out of the loop will yield significantly faster results**

```
datafiles = glob.glob("raw_data/*.txt")   

for u in users:
        content = ""
        filestring = "_" + str(u) + ".txt"
        contentfiles = [i for i in datafiles if filestring in i]
        for c in contentfiles:
            txt = open(c, "r").read()
            content += txt
```

Comment: Do you know which part is slow? If the glob part, there is probably no need to do it for every user, you could take it out of the loop completely. And in all likelihood, your text files are not large enough to take 1 second to read or write.

Comment: @Keldorn If I remove the glob part, how can I get the right files? Thanks.

Comment: Move it out of the loop, but still have it somewhere before. E.g. `allcontentfiles = glob.glob("raw_data/" + "*_*.txt")` before the loop, then you have your 400k file names in memory. Or maybe more, if more than one file per user. Then in the `for u in users` loop, get the right files from `allcontentfiles`. If too many files, start with all users starting with an `a`, etc.
But again, that is based on the my assumption that the slow part is the glob. You could profile that.

Comment: Do you have to do it in Python? Maybe in bash it could be faster to cat all files from each folder and stream it to a single file, something like `cat * > output.txt`

Comment: @Keldorn I moved the `glob` bit outside of the loop, and it made it around 20 times faster.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the assumption that the `glob` is the bottleneck, then in the edit the list filtering is the new bottleneck, here is a proposition:

- move `glob` out of the loop to make it just once
- do the list filtering just once, if at all
- do not store the content in a temporary variable

```py
datafiles = glob.glob("raw_data/*.txt")   
userfiles = {} # Dictionary of "user: [file list]"

# Prepare the file list
for file in datafiles:
    user = file.split('.')[-2].split('_')[-1]
    ufiles = userfiles.get(user, default=[])
    ufiles.append(file)
    userfiles[user] = ufiles

# Loop over the list
for user, ufiles in userfiles.items():
    with open("docs/{}.txt".format(user), "w") as outfile:
        for infile in ufiles:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
```

You could probably even do without filtering the files per user at all, just looping over arbitrarily ordered files in `datafiles`. That means opening `outfile` in append mode (`a`), so that the original content is not overwritten with every new file for a user.